# Would a nictitating membrane, eyelid AND eyelashes get in each other's way in the same eye?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, bio-mechanics

Or would that eye be the most well-defended from external debris and whatnot in the entire world? Cats seem to get by just fine without eyelids and a membrane but no eyelashes...likewise humans with lashes and lids but no membranes...

Comment: Greetings and welcome to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange! Keep up with the good questions here, and in the meantime, be sure to check out the [tour] and the [help] for more information on how this forum works, the culture and so forth!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**NO.**

[image]

Cats actually have eye lashes, two eye lids and a nictitating membrane. They also have furry eye lids. Unless the cat suffers from [trichiasis](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/trichiasis), there won't be a problem.

Ostriches as well:

[image]

Humans have what's left of a nictitating membrane, the plica:

[image]

Comment: I actually picked up my cat and looked when I saw the title to this question.  Cheers for including the feline reality!

Comment: Cats are wonderful little creatures indeed! I very much hope you properly worshipped your Cat today!

Comment: @elemtilas ...maybe i didn't say it right, but humans have upper eyelids that visibly move down and back up our eye when we blink, but when cats/dogs/etc blink, their WHOLE EYE moves? It doesn't look the same and formerly I thought that meant it wasn't? Clarification please?

Comment: Do you mean the eye ball itself moves? It does, for humans as well as cats. As for the eyelids, both eyelids move, but a little differently and for different kinds of blinking. The most exaggerated lower lid movement happens when you squint

Comment: @elemtilas ... it just looks different when I see my cat do it. There's no 'fold' I guess is what I'm trying to say?

Comment: Fold? I guess I don't understand quite you're looking at!